# efficiently Iterating with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I made code that calculates the average value for each element in period p for array y

```
import numpy as np
p=4

y =np.asarray([146, 96, 59, 133, 192, 127, 79, 186, 272, 155, 98, 219])

c=len(y)/p
print c

a=[]
for i in range(1,c+1):
    s=y[p*(i-1):p*i]/np.mean(y[p*(i-1):p*i])
    a = np.append(a, s)
print a

b=[]
for i in range(c+1):
    s = np.mean(a[i::p])
    b = np.append(b, s)

print b
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this instead of using append and the for loops? I do not need both arrays just b

Comment: To get rid of the append, allocate two arrays of ints using np.zeros(shape), then assign to the relevant index and you should see a performance boost.  Also, what's the end goal of this script? That might help us give you a hand...

Comment: Probably, second range should be also in `range(p)`, as you iterate modulo p: `a[i::p]`. I updated answer, last result equals your expected b, but is one item longer, since c=3 but p=4.

Comment: @MadisonMay adding Holt-Winters exponential smoothing, this is used for calculating the seasons

Comment: @user3084006 see updates in my answer

Comment: @alko That is what I am working on. But for Statsmodel. I got all the double and single down with all the multiplicative models and dampening variations too. I will submit it after I finish the triple and the prediction bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you do a 2d operation. Your first array, a, can be evalueated if a second demension added (for example with reshape):

```
z = y.reshape(-1, p)
w = z/z.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
print w.flatten()
# [ 1.34562212  0.88479263  0.5437788   1.22580645  1.31506849  0.86986301
#   0.54109589  1.2739726   1.46236559  0.83333333  0.52688172  1.17741935]
```

Your second, `b`, is a mean of previous result:

```
print w.mean(axis=0)
# [ 1.37435207,  0.86266299,  0.53725214,  1.2257328 ]
```

**Update**

As you mention exponential smoothing in comments, you might be interested in [`pandas`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/) or [`statsmodels`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels) packages to deal with timeseries. See for example pandas docs with some useful [computational tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-moment-functions) and [this ER](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2143) in issue tracker for some useful links about exponential smoothing implementation.

Comment: I am basing the calculations method from http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc435.htm and using the data from http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=1230

But it seems like I am getting the wrong numbers for S (first 4 numbers for the seasonal index) or the calculation method at adorio-research might be wrong

Comment: if y has an remainder can is the best way to coerce it to work in the reshape function to do an if statement then  `w = z[:len(y) % p*-1].reshape(-1, p)`