# Holt winters initial Seasonal Indices calculation in python

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, smoothing

I am having trouble finding the correct calculations for the seasonal indicies for the Holt Winters exponential smoothing.

I used the calculation method from [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc435.htm) and used data from [adorio-research](http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=1230)

```
z =[146, 96, 59, 133, 192, 127, 79, 186, 272, 155, 98, 219]


Results:
s= [ 1.3744  0.8627  0.5373  1.2257]
```

The calculations using the NIST method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872202/efficiently-iterating-with-numpy) on Stackoverflow. But for [adorio-research](http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=1230) they got different results with the same values.

```
Results:
S= [ 1.4789  0.8985  0.5152  1.1074]
```

Did I calculate something wrong or is the code for adorio-research using a different method to calculate the initial seasonal indices?

Comment: Related http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10378/using-holt-winters-for-forecasting-in-python

Comment: @cyborg do you know where I can get a dataset with correct results that I can check against?

Answer (score 0):

The Holt-Winters code from  is WRONG. You can check at the link below which uses R code to calculate Holt-Winters

http://www.wessa.net/rwasp_exponentialsmoothing.wasp#output

Enter the data below and set `season period at 4`, `Type of Exponential Smoothing to Triple`, `Type of seasonality to multiplicative`  in the link

```
146
96
59
133
192
127
79
186
272
155
98
219
```

It will return you with parameters for alpha, beta and gamma

```
alpha   0.735716596454859
beta    0.0382359201508119
gamma   1
```

and the results

```
t   Observed    Fitted            Residuals
5   192        170.088248700704   21.9117512992958
6   127        122.981857107346   4.01814289265398
7   79         75.9008222744013   3.09917772559865
8   186        172.139757560624   13.8602424393755
9   272        272.260398525039   -0.260398525038966
10  155        173.023900179977   -18.0239001799769
11  98         95.2888315311983   2.71116846880174
12  219        213.920670513984   5.07932948601567
```

Plug the alpha, beta, and gamma into the python code and you get:

```
holtwinters(y, 0.735716596454859, 0.0382359201508119, 1,4)

[ 158.3686  113.11     73.8393  175.5253  262.0823  176.5653  112.4055
  268.6787  401.3833  243.3259  150.7145  343.6221]
```

As you can see its WRONG. But the R model uses Error correction so it would also be determined on how you set the initial points.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization isn't formally defined for Holt Winters, and a variety of techniques have been suggested in the literature. [This post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/hw-initialization/) by Hyndman describes a sensible, effective procedure.

An easy to use python package (that also estimates the period of your data) is `seasonal` (available on PyPI or [here](https://github.com/welch/seasonal))